# Mysqlbug: Could not find a text editor. (tried emacs)

Tags: mysql

I want to check with what configurations mysql was configured. I found that mysqlbug can retrieve that info, but i'm getting the following error:

```
mysqlbug
Finding system information for a MySQL bug report
test -x 
Could not find a text editor. (tried emacs)
You can change editor by setting the environment variable VISUAL.
If your shell is a bourne shell (sh) do
VISUAL=your_editors_name; export VISUAL
If your shell is a C shell (csh) do
setenv VISUAL your_editors_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried what it's already telling you to do?

```
You can change editor by setting the environment variable VISUAL.
If your shell is a bourne shell (sh) do
VISUAL=your_editors_name; export VISUAL
If your shell is a C shell (csh) do
setenv VISUAL your_editors_name
```

in place of 'your_editors_name' you would place the name of whatever editor you know how to use.  vi (or vim), nano, pico, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the error message itself.  If you are using Bash, run `export VISUAL=vi`
before running `mysqlbug`.  Or, pick another editor instead of `vi`, such as `pico`.